# SQL Server select query with multiple joins give timeout

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a SQL select that is a little bit complex as it has several relationships with other tables and it's taking forever and finally giving timeout so I'm stuck and maybe someone here could help me to find the problem or optimizing it.

For you to have some context the select gets AREAS and there are many other entities that have an idArea. An area also has a central (the building where it is located) and there are other entities like PCI that have a c_central field that relates to area also.

I have a winform where I can filter the AREAS table to locate certain areas and for that I have several textboxes or comboboxes where I can enter filtering information (you'll see it in the where clause).

I have copied the SELECT below and inserted several line breaks so it's easier to read.

One important note, if I take out the PCI LEFT OUTER JOIN and corresponding PCI WHERE it works.

Many thanks in advance.

```
SELECT dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_grupo, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_area, 
          dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.d_area, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.ficha, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.rev_numero, 
          dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.rev_fecha_creacion, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.elevacion, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_central,
          dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci1, dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci2, dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.localizacion
          
          FROM dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbGESFAI_PENETRACION_A 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = dbo.tbGESFAI_PENETRACION_A.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONFIJA 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONFIJA.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_RECINTO 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = tbGESFAI_RECINTO.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbGESFAI_PUERTA_DETALLE_A 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = dbo.tbGESFAI_PUERTA_DETALLE_A.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONMOVIL 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONMOVIL.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbGESFAI_COMPUERTA_DETALLE_A 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = dbo.tbGESFAI_COMPUERTA_DETALLE_A.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_PCI 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_central = tbGESFAI_PCI.c_central 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_DETECCION 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = tbGESFAI_DETECCION.idArea 
          
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tbGESFAI_ALARMA 
          ON dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id = tbGESFAI_ALARMA.idArea  
          
          WHERE dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_central = 'A' 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_PENETRACION_A.identificacion LIKE ('%a%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONFIJA.EstacionControl LIKE ('%a%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_area LIKE ('%0%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_RECINTO.d_rec LIKE ('%1%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_PUERTA_DETALLE_A.puerta LIKE ('%1%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_EXTINCIONMOVIL.tag LIKE ('%1%') 
          AND dbo.tbGESFAI_COMPUERTA_DETALLE_A.compuerta LIKE ('%1%') 
          AND (dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci1 LIKE ('%c2%') 
          OR dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci2 LIKE ('%c2%') 
          OR dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.LOCALIZACION LIKE ('%c2%')) 
          AND (dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_estado = 'H' 
          OR dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_estado = 'V' 
          OR dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_estado = 'F') 
          
          GROUP BY dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.id, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_grupo, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_area, 
          dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.d_area, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.ficha, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.rev_numero, 
          dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.rev_fecha_creacion, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.elevacion, dbo.tbGESFAI_AREA.c_central, 
          dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci1, dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.pci2, dbo.tbGESFAI_PCI.localizacion
          
          ORDER BY c_area
```

Comment: All those like statements are not going to help.

Comment: Why you say that Tom? I don't understand your answer. I need to filter.

Comment: All your tables mentioned in "like" statements will be scanned, tbGESFAI_PCI will be scanned three times

Comment: Thanks both for replying. Then how to optimize it Denis?

Comment: So when you use a like statement SQL then searches every row for that pattern.  For example `dbo.tbGESFAI_PENETRACION_A.identificacion LIKE ('%a%')` is looking at EVERY row for the letter a. So if you have thousands of rows in that column, they are all getting looked at.

Comment: if you post some example data we can have a look at how to optimize.

Comment: But I'm specifying the column, the column in this case of your example is "identification". Why you say it will look in every column?

Comment: Sorry typo it looks at every row in that column

Comment: updated, so it should make more sense haha

Comment: I understand Tom, I guess my query is well written but not optimized. It's very difficult for me to paste data here because there are many related tables and I don't know how to do it.

Should I use an index for example? Could it help in my case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163936/discussion-between-tom-and-diego-perez).

Comment: After a while investigating I finally realized I had a LEFT OUTER JOIN causing a big "loop" (cartesian product) which was causing the timeout so now my problem is solved.

Thank you very much both @Tom and Denis for your time and help, I appreciate it very much and will close the case.